# How to setup timezone xampp mysql and apache?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, xampp

I am using XAMPP - PHP and MYSQL servers. When I tried to use following -

```
getRates(date('Y-m-d'));



function getRates($cDate)
{
$query = "SELECT * FROM randa WHERE date like '$cDate'" //it only worked at times.  
}

?>
```

Then I realized the date('Y-m-d') does not return the correct date. Went to php.ini and changed time zone. And is still returning the wrong date.

How can I fix this ?
Thank you

Comment: `date like`? why are you doing this?

Comment: my.ini `default_time_zone=Brazil/East` if you cant change the whole db, you can change it per connection `mysql_query("SET time_zone = 'Australia/Sydney'", $this->_connection);`

Comment: first I used date =, then date like, thought that would fix the problem.

Answer (score 25):

Try this

1)  In httpd.conf (\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf) , add the following line:

```
SetEnv TZ Europe/Moscow
```

2) Edit php.ini (\xampp\php\php.ini) date.timezone value in [Date] section:

```
date.timezone = "Europe/Moscow"
```

3) In my.ini (\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini) add or replace

```
default-time-zone = "Europe/Moscow"
```

Restart Apache and MySQL

Comment: Do not use named timezone unless you had timezone data populated on your mysql database. Instead use an offset relative to the UTC. For example: default-time-zone = "+01:00" for CET.
Read more:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: @Rulisp I have tried all the 3 steps, and restarted the services. But MySQL doesn't starts.

Comment: @Rulisp I am also having the same issue.After adding 3rd point cant able to start mysql.

Comment: @Rahul well, 3 years passed since I left this answer. Could you tell me mysql version?

Comment: @Rulisp MYSQL version: 5.6.20

Comment: @Rahul try to replace `Europe/Moscow` with appropriate UTC offset

Comment: on number 3, which `[Section]` should I put `default-time-zone = "Europe/Moscow"` ?

Comment: Use `default-time-zone = "+08:00"`

Comment: That "offset" thing is not going to work in places that have "Daylight Savings Time". You'd have to keep changing it when that time-change happens. I've gotten the 'time zone' thing to work by stopping XAMPP, changing the time zone **on my laptop System Time** to my desired zone, then restarting XAMPP. After that,  my queries picked up my desired time zone.

Answer (score 3):

Please add this code on your top page.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

Search your country here 
http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Answer (score 0):

Solved: but feeling stupid.

my local machine had the correct time however, time zone was incorrect. Changed the time zone and it worked. I don't understand why though. The time WAS CORRECT. Zone was not.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL stores datetime as [yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss] at the UTC timezone. Your field in the db may be set up incorrectly but it may help if you post it's parameters. You shouldn't need to change settings in the conf or php.ini files. I suspect the difference between UTC and your timezone is making the query fail at certain times of the day because the UTC timestamp has passed into the next day. You may need to compensate your date prior to making the query by adding (or subtracting) the right amount of time so the datetime matches UTC. 
Something like this:
getRates(date("Y-m-d h:i:sa",(yourtimestamp + (7 * 60 * 60))));
Or declare the timezone prior to the query:
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");