# What does "Europe/Berlin" represent in the XAMPP PHP log file?

Tags: php, xampp

What does the "**Europe/Berline]**" portion of the error code, located in the php_error_log files, represent?

The php_error_log file is located on XAMPP in the Windows directory: C:\xampp\php\logs.

Here are a few of the error codes:

```
[18-Apr-2015 04:56:38 **Europe/Berlin]** PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\tests\index_test.php on line 10

[18-Apr-2015 04:57:14 **Europe/Berlin]** PHP Fatal error:  Class 'some\directory\Config' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\index.php on line 17

[18-Apr-2015 05:02:16 **Europe/Berlin]** PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp2\src\index.php on line 36
```

Comment: I am located in the United States, EST.

Comment: Then something has been set up incorrectly

Comment: I checked my Time Zone settings <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269364/how-to-setup-timezone-xampp-mysql-and-apache> and nothing has been set.

Comment: The question you linked is about setting the timezone for MySQL, not for PHP. Check the php.ini file instead.

Comment: Yes, I have checked the php.ini file. There are no time zone settings. The question I linked does show the php.ini file.

Comment: Have you confirmed that PHP is using the same php.ini file that you think it is? Use `phpinfo()` to confirm. Also, check that there isn't a second timezone setting further down php.ini that might be overriding the first one. Finally, if you did have to change any ini settings, remember to restart Apache, otherwise the change won't take effect.

Comment: Using phpinfo() I confirmed the location of the php.ini file. I checked this file previously and did not find the time zone settings with a "Find" search. Checked it again and found it. 

Around line 1042 the settings were: 
date.timezone=Europe/Berlin
I changed it to:
date.timezone=America/New_York

Thanks everyone for the help. Please give this question a plus :)

Comment: This leads to another question: Is Europe/Berline the default setting in php.ini for an XAMPP install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is that this is the Time Zone. The time zone is set in the php.ini file and is recorded in error logs.