# Unable to set Xampp MySQL timezone in my.ini file

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Referring to the question asked, I know that there are alot of questions related to it but I am unable to set the time zone for `mysql` in `my.ini` file. I have searched this problem over the internet, i found many solutions and implemented them but still couldn't able to get the desired result. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26269424/6789930) are the settings i have done. Time zone is `Asia/Karachi`

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: did you restarted sever after those changes?

Comment: @AlivetoDie yes i did